# PNG Graphics won't display in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have trouble with graphics in LaTeX. I am using Kil under ubuntu.

I first tried including .png images, then got the classic no bounding box error.
When I switched to .eps, I got no errors but no images in the input!

Included graphics package:

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
```

And used a simple:

```
\includegraphics{figures/arch2.eps}
```

Comment: Please post (excerpts of) the .log file.

Comment: Which compilation scheme do you use?  What is the output format?

Comment: you don't need to put the file extension in the `\includegraphics` command. This allows you to have a .eps and .png with the same name, and the appropriate one will be loaded depending on whether you're using latex or pdftex

Answer (score 3):

you must include the package `\usepackage{epstopdf}`

Answer (score 1):

This error is normal if you use latex for conversion, so I'm almost sure you're not using pdftex for conversion, as you should if you want to insert  figures other than eps.